# Google+ Sign-in Button in iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, safari, google-plus

I have integrated google+ signin into a php-based web application. It works great in desktop browsers but in iOS6 Safari pressing the signin button does not trigger the appropriate behavior. If I open the app subsequently, it does work, suggesting an issue with caching. I've created a stripped down version, (similar to the one on the google site) of this at http://www.purpool.com/po/test.html . (It doesn't include any of the javascript handlers needed to complete the authentication.) Does anyone have suggestions as to fixing this?

I might add that in iOS6 Chrome the button works but the full authentication process (the opening of a new tab where the user agrees to the service, etc..) does not work as smoothly as it should.

Thanks for your help.

Peter

Comment: I should note that the Google Developers Site example of this (https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) works in iOS6 Safari but the button is inside an iframe. This button doesn't function properly when the iframe is opened directly (https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) and exhibits the same issues I describe above.  I tried putting my code in a frame but that didn't solve the issue...

Comment: Using the Google Developers Site example (developers.google.com/+/web/signin) as scaffolding, I have created a stripped down example that works on iOS at http://www.purpool.com/po/stackoverflow/g-signin.html . The google+ sign-in button is embedded in an iframe and there are some style rules that seem critical for the button to be clickable. The whole business is still a mystery to me but at least now I can proceed to the actual php-based web application. (Keep in mind that my example doesn't include code to complete the authentication.)